# Reference sheet name to move to next sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have sequential tabs (`1` up to `100`). I need code to move between tabs sequentially. However, the code must reference the tab name (eg., `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, etc.) because the tabs are created later on.  I have this so far:

```
Sub Next_Page()
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name + 1).Visible = True
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name + 1).Activate
End Sub
```

It is referencing the second ActiveSheet in the workbook instead of the tab titled `2`. To make matters more confusing, if I have this return the code in a message box instead, I properly get `2`. Without quotes, this is the result.

Comment: Try `Sheets(CStr(ActiveSheet.Name + 1))`.

Answer (score 0):

A worksheet can be referred to by its [Worksheet.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa175750(v=office.11).aspx) or its [Worksheet.Index property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836415.aspx) (among others).

The **.Name** property is always a string; even if that string looks like a number or date. The **.Index** property is always a true number between 1 and the number of worksheets in the workbook (e.g. [Worksheets.Count property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834982.aspx)).

Your method of adding **1** to the [ActiveSheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb212495%28v=office.12%29.aspx)'s name has the action of converting what was a string looking like a number into an actual true number. You need to convert it back to a string.

```
Sub Next_Page()
    Sheets(CStr(ActiveSheet.Name + 1)).Visible = True
    Sheets(CStr(ActiveSheet.Name + 1)).Activate
End Sub
```

Your code has no doubt been simplified but I would advise toward putting in something that checks to make sure that `Sheets(CStr(ActiveSheet.Name + 1))` exists as would be the case if you were already on worksheet **4** since there is no worksheet named **5**.

Comment: Thank you!! When I made reference the string it worked! Also, using the error check function as well so it goes to a default page in that event. Thanks!!